# Make std::fill call a non const qualified operator overload

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading, constants

I was trying to fill an array with numbers `1 - 100`. I used `std::fill`. Now, `std::fill`'s last argument is the number to fill the range with. I thought I could be clever, and pass in a object that has an `int` overload, so when it assigns the range element, it will also auto increment the number in the object.

```
class AutoInc {

public:

    operator int() {
        number++;
        return number - 1;
    }

    int number = 1;

};
```

... and for the following call to `std::fill`:

```
int numbers[100];
std::fill(numbers, numbers + 99, (AutoInc());
```

It threw an error, saying it could not find an int overload for AutoInc. This is because `std::fill` takes a const-reference, and because the int overload isn't const, it will not call that. When I change the overload to const qualified, and I do not modify `number`, the program works (without filling the array properly of course). Is there a way around this? I know I can use a for loop to fill the array, but I'm talking about other STL functions that take a const-reference too.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota

Comment: @Brian yes that helps (actually solves my problem), but what about other STL functions that take a const-reference. What do I do then?

Comment: By the way, no one guaratees you that the same object would be used to fill your array! Implementation might as well use a new copy for every assignment (made from original).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your question is really about whether you can force STL algorithms to call non-`const` member functions on objects passed by `const` reference, the answer is simply that you cannot.

One workaround is to mark `number` as a `mutable` member. Then a `const` member function would be allowed to modify it.

However, I suggest that you think very carefully before doing something of this sort. There may be a good reason why the function takes a `const` reference. In the case of `std::fill`, the standard actually does not specify that the range must be filled in any particular order. If you pass in something that yields a different `int` value every time it's called, then there is no guarantee that you get `1 2 3 4` ... But if you pass in something that doesn't use any tricks like this, then it doesn't matter what the order is, and you always get the same result.

As I pointed out in a comment, `std::iota` is what you should be using in this case. In a more general case, you want `std::generate`, which fills a range by calling a function object which is passed by value.

Answer (score 1):

One option you can use is qualify `number` to be `mutable`.

```
mutable int number = 1;
```

Then you can use:

```
operator int() const {
    return number++;
}
```

However, as was suggested in a comment, you are better off using [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota).